# SQL Include 0 with Decimals

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

#### Orders (o)

```
id   name            price       quantity
---------------------------------------------
1    Candy           0.69        5
2    Brownies        5.99        1
```

I'm currently doing this query:

```
SELECT o.id, CONCAT(o.price, ' * ', o.quantity) AS formula
FROM orders o
```

It works but I get the following result:

```
id    formula
---------------------------------------
1     .69 * 5
2     5.99 * 1
```

What changes to the query do I need in order to get `0.69` instead of `.69`?

Comment: to_char(price,'9999.99')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_char()` to convert a string to a number.  A 0 includes leading zeros:

```
SELECT o.id,
       (TO_CHAR(o.price, '0.00') || ' * ' || o.quantity) AS formula
FROM orders o;
```

In Oracle, `concat()` only takes two arguments.  `||` is the more traditional method of doing concatenation.

Comment: Worked, thanks! What's the difference between using `'0.00'` instead of `'9999.99'` as SkyWalker mentioned? His solution didn't work for me but yours did.

Comment: The difference in the format models is documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm

Comment: @PatrickGregorio . . . 9's in a numeric format just represent any digit, but no leading zeros.  0's are always there, even when the number is too short.